# Mac ABRecord setValue forProperty error

Tags: macos, cocoa

When I use AddressBook like this :

```
ABAddressBook *ab = [ABAddressBook addressBook];  
ABPerson *person = [[ABPerson alloc]init];  
[person setValue:lastName forProperty:kABLastNameProperty];  
[ab addRecord:person];  
[ab save];
```

I got error :

```
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001448a0'`
```

What does `setValue:forProperty` do

Comment: `setValue:forProperty:` sets the record's value for a property. More details, as usual, are in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABRecord_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABRecord/setValue:forProperty:

Comment: how is `lastName` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in

```
-[__NSCFString count]
```

The `setValue:forProperty` sets value for a property. It looks like the problem might be your `lastName` object that you are trying to set.

Comment: The Value must be an array?

Comment: @chroww: Not according to the documentation. stefanB isn't wrong (there's definitely a string where some other kind of object was expected), but there's something else going on here.